# javascript - have promises call at end of for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, cloud, promise

I have this code and I want to make the code wait until the asyncrnous query called prom has finessed before restarting the first for loop. So the array will be reset, before it starts the first for loop again.

```
items = [];
var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {

        items.length = 0;
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < test.length; i2++) {

            var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
            var queryUserFav = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);
            queryUserFav.equalTo('item', test[i2].get('item'));
            queryUserFav.equalTo('school', test[i2].get('school'));
            queryUserFav.equalTo('user1', userArray[i])
            var prom = queryUserFav.find().then(function(res) {


                    for (var i3 = 0; i3 < res.length; i3++){
                        var item = res[i3];
                        var itemName = item.get('item');
                        items.push(itemName);
                        console.log(items)

                    }
                    return items;


            });
            promises.push(prom);

        }
        //return Parse.Promise.when.apply(Parse.Promise, promises); I have tried it here but
        // this just stops the first for loop after its first loop

    }
    return Parse.Promise.when.apply(Parse.Promise, promises);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is have a chain of promises, one for each item in an array.

If would be nice if javascript had an equivalent of .NET's `await` keyword, where you could go

```
 await Parse.Promise.when(promises)
```

and then it allowed the promise code to run then returned back to running any code after the `await`. But Javascript doesn't give this to us.

---

Another approach is to maintain an `index` variable. After every set of queries is processed, you increment the `index` variable and process the next set of values.

```
 function parseForUser(user) {
      var promises = [];
      for (var i2 = 0; i2 < test.length; i2++) {
        var items = [];
        var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
        var queryUserFav = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);
        queryUserFav.equalTo('item', test[i2].get('item'));
        queryUserFav.equalTo('school', test[i2].get('school'));
        queryUserFav.equalTo('user1', user)
        var prom = queryUserFav.find().then(function(res) {
                for (var i3 = 0; i3 < res.length; i3++){
                    var item = res[i3];
                    var itemName = item.get('item');
                    items.push(itemName);
                    console.log(items)

                }
                return items;
        });
        promises.push(prom);
      }
      return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

 }


 function parseUserArray(userArray) {
     var returnPromise = new Parse.Promise(); // Do you have to call it via new? 
                                              //The documentation isn't clear.
     var index = 0;
     var doNext = function() {
         if(index < userArray.length) {
            var promise = parseForUser(userArray[index++]);
            promise.done(doNext);
         } else {
             returnPromise.resolve(); 
         }
     }
     doNext();
     return returnPromise;
 }

 var parseUserArrayPromise = parseUserArray(userArray);
```

Comment: my query depends on the variable i how can I call it where you said when i isn't declared?

Comment: @spenf - Your query doesn't really depend on the variable `i`, it depends on the user at `userArray[i]`. Note that this code `parseForUser` takes a user object as a parameter.

Comment: okay, Im just a little confused on how to put in the query code?

Comment: @spenf - I've included that in the code example now. Note that I haven't tested this, it's just giving you an approach to the problem.

Comment: Some text describing the general idea in your solution would make your answer a better answer.

Comment: right I ran it and it runs, but it still groups all the output in one array, I don't see in your code where you are reseting the array length? I put an edit where I think it might be...

Comment: @spenf - I think your edit was rejected, so I've just declared a new `items` array inside the loop.

Comment: it was but add that line make it work. Would you mind adding in some comments explain step by step how this code works, because its a great answer I just can't seem to see how it flows if I were to reproduce something similar. thanks

Comment: Worth mentioning that on the server (node.js) you have something very similar to `await` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW ...

This solution differs from @AndrewShepherd's chiefly in that here we take double advantage of the promise returned by `asyncProcessUser()`.

- firstly for flow control - the asynchronous sequencing of the inner loop
- secondly for delivering an array of results, from which the final array of results is built, avoiding the need for an outer `promises` array.

```js
function parseUserArray(userArray, test) {

    // This function is the original inner for() loop, now expressed as a .map(), 
    // (plus peripheral wrapping and chaining).
    // It asynchronously processes a single user against all test items,
    // and returns a promise of an array of results.
    // The promise resolves when all the individual .finds complete.
    function asyncProcessUser(user) {
        return Parse.Promise.when(test.map(function(dataItem) {
            return (new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite")))
                .equalTo('item', dataItem.get('item'))
                .equalTo('school', dataItem.get('school'))
                .equalTo('user1', user)
                .find().then(function(res) {
                    return res.map(function(r) {
                        return r.get('item');
                    });
                });
        })).then(function() {
            return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).reduce(function(arr, arr_) {
                return arr.concat(arr_);
            }, []);
        });
    }

    // This is the original outer for() loop, now expressed as a .reduce(), which is 
    // a common pattern for performing a series of async tasks (ie what was the inner loop).
    // Here, `userArray.reduce(...)` returns a promise of an array of 
    // the objects returned by `r.get('item')` above.
    return userArray.reduce( function(p, user) {
        return p.then(function(arr) {
            return asyncProcessUser(user).then(function(arr_) {
                return arr.concat(arr_);
            });
        });
    }, Parse.Promise.as([]) );//† "returns a new promise that is resolved with a given value".
}
```

† : [Documentation for Parse.Promise.as()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.as)

Without the comments, it's quite concise.

The concept is demonstrated *[here](http://jsfiddle.net/teojk6m7/2/)*. Don't worry that the demo uses jQuery promises, it's the concept that matters.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
function parseForUser(user) {
      var promises = [];
      for (var i2 = 0; i2 < test.length; i2++) {
        var items = [];
        var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
        var queryUserFav = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);
        queryUserFav.equalTo('item', test[i2].get('item'));
        queryUserFav.equalTo('school', test[i2].get('school'));
        queryUserFav.equalTo('user1', user)
        var prom = queryUserFav.find().then(function(res) {
                for (var i3 = 0; i3 < res.length; i3++){
                    var item = res[i3];
                    var itemName = item.get('item');
                    items.push(itemName);
                    console.log(items)

                }
                return items;
        });
        promises.push(prom);
      }
      return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

 }


 function parseUserArray(userArray) {
     var returnPromise = new Parse.Promise(); // Do you have to call it via new? 
                                              //The documentation isn't clear.
     var index = 0;
     var doNext = function() {
         if(index < userArray.length) {
            var promise = parseForUser(userArray[index++]);
            promise.done(doNext);
         } else {
             returnPromise.resolve(); 
         }
     }
     doNext();
     return returnPromise;
 }
```

Just copy and paste